# About total variation distance

Tags: measure-theory

Assume we have two probability measure $P,Q$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and 
$$d_{tv}(P,Q) = \sup_{A\subset\mathbb{R}^n} |P(A)-Q(A)|.$$
Can we find $A^*\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $d_{tv}(P,Q)=P(A^*)-Q(A^*)$ ?

Comment: I guess the $\sup_{A\subset \mathbb{R}^n}$ should only consider measureable subsets $A$

Comment: Yes. Just for convenience, i didn't write it..

Comment: I think not, as after all the definition is written with $\sup$ and not $\max$.